# Conversion of Word and Excel documents to PDF using ITEXTSHARP

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Whether Word and Excel documents can be covertable to PDF using **ITEXTSHARP** in  c# .Net? Or any possible means of achieving this other than using Microsoft Interops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, iTextSharp cannot convert Word/Excel/PowerPoint/Visio files to PDF.

The longer answer is that if you can "somehow" get data from those file formats you can then use iTextSharp to create a PDF. It is 100% up to you to figure out the "somehow", iTextSharp won't help you there. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828368/231316) which goes into it further.

Comment: Thanks Chris Haas, will have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use open source libraries (like EPPlus for reading/writing Excel) and use with ITextSharp.

It's fairly simplistic to use.